# Favourite tag questions aren't clear enough

Tags: feature-request, design, bookmarks

One thing that's been bothering me since the release of the bicycles.se theme is the highlighting of favourite tags. I don't know if it's just me but I find the questions with favourite tags very difficult to see. I shouldn't be straining to see something that needs to be seen at a glance.

Take a look at the difference between the backgrounds on favourite questions on Bicycle.se and the beta theme for Bricks.se. (The text boldness is irrelevent as it doesn't vary for favourite questions)

[image]

I'd suggest a light colour that matches the sites colour pallete.

**Related:** [Review contrast of regular vs favorite color for various Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127663/157163)

Comment: @freiheit, I've removed your tag. This is a feature request not a bug.

Comment: The difference between the white and the yellow tint is very clear on my screen. Maybe you could fiddle around with the contrast settings on your screen? It may be off.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not more of a font issue than a color contrast issue?  When I look at the site, the fonts are thicker, less jagged, and visibility isn't an issue...

What's your setup?

[image]

Screenshot from a different system:

[image]

Comment: No. There is no difference in font between questions with and without favourite tags. It's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Ambo100: What I mean is that you're getting a different font for Bicycles than for Bricks with much thinner lines that don't contrast as clearly. Look at the upper-case "W" in both of your examples.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome on a display of 1280 by 1024 pixels monitor display. I hadn't noticed any difference until you had made it clear but it hasn't been a problem for me.

Comment: @Ambo100 do you have ClearType rendering turned on? I assume you're using Windows XP or Vista?

Comment: @Jin: No, I don't. I have enabled it now anyway. My issue is with the background colour not being clear enough.